# Synonym [instagram] into [instagram-api]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Let's get [instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) synonymed into [instagram-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram-api). I can't think of any use of [Instagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instagram) that wouldn't be done through their API.

Comment: Are there off-topic questions in [[tag:instagram]] that need to be cleaned up first? What you can imagine isn’t really relevant...

Comment: One possible counterexample: using Instagram as an OAuth provider

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unpopular.

Comment: @DanielA.White That's not a valid reason to close a question.

Comment: @DanielA.White - just leave it be, after all, this is a discussion - maybe someone will make a valid point and change the tide (see Braiam's answer for example)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think we should make [instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) a synonym of [instagram-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram-api). Programmatic interaction with a platform for whatever reason should not be put into one pot with the usage of the API which may change, be renamed and shutdown completely without affecting platform as a whole<sup>0</sup>.

---

[Updated data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1264602#resultSets) on question closure shows that from 9641 questions tagged with [instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram), 1325 were Closed, amounting to 13% closure ratio. At the same time, [instagram-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram-api) has 400 out of 4395 questions closed, resulting in a 9% closure ratio. Both ratios are within acceptable boundaries (for example, [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) has [12%](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1264602/questions-tagged-with-tag-that-were-closed?tag=c%2B%2B), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) has [11%](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1264602/questions-tagged-with-tag-that-were-closed?tag=java), [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) [11%](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1264602/questions-tagged-with-tag-that-were-closed?tag=facebook))

**Non-API usage**

[instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) can be used for questions about web scraping. Below is the graph of question activity tagged with [instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) and containing "scrape" in question body:

[image: instagram-tag with scrape in body graph]

As a pure metadata alternative, below is the usage graph of [instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) paired with [web-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) tag showing a similar dynamic:

[image: instagram and web-scraping tag]

And here is how the graph looks like for [instagram-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram-api):

[image: instagram-api tag with scrape in body graph]

The difference is not overwhelming, but still, noticeable - [instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) is more likely to be used for questions about web-scraping than [instagram-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram-api) (which is understandable since the API is not involved here).

---

Also, some people use [instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) to ask questions about platform styling (not many of them, but still):

[image: instagram tag with css tag]

Compare this to how [instagram-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram-api) and [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) are used together (take note that its usage only started this year, which might indicate a need in cleanup more than anything):

[image: instagram-api tag with css tag]

Finally, to provide some hard data to Ryan's counter-example, usage of [instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) with questions that contain "oauth" seems to suggest that OAuth issues are more or less evenly distributed and usage died down since 2016:

[image: instagram tag with oauth]

[image: instagram-api tag with oauth]

---

<sup>0</sup> For that matter, we should've never synonymized [google-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) to [google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api) and [google-calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar) to [google-calendar-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api) for same reasons, but here we are.

Comment: That closing stat is wholly inaccurate. Most closed questions are deleted at the 9 days mark. There are 1503 closed, 4399 deleted for a total of 9641 questions with the instagram tag. That puts your ratio at 15.5% of questions closed and 45.6% deleted.

Comment: @Braiam - hm, that's a good catch, thank you, I will modify to include corrected data. Does not mean that there is only one use case for the tag, though

Comment: I recommend you squinting hard at those questions, all of the ones that I've seen that aren't about the api are either off topic or aren't about instagram at all. :)

Comment: @Braiam - after seeing your link to an example, I think this warrants an investigation indeed :) I'll take a look and update with the results

Answer (score 0):

So, I've reviewed some [instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) top voted questions and I've found that all of them are about the api, in fact 3 out 5 had the [instagram-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram-api) tag already applied. I would get behind a merge of this, and considering that most of the non-api questions are the only ones that are getting closed/deleted ([>80% of all [tag:instagram] questions do not have an api tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1266149)). Maybe that would slow down the growth of the off topic ones.

Obviously, a review of the now new [instagram-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram-api) questions may be required ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15470180/792066)).